# .NET - Tagging an EC2 Instance using AWS CDK for .NET's low-level CloudFormation Resource constructs

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

While we all wait for a higher-level / hand-written [Construct](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/constructs.html) to be available for creating an EC2 instance using AWS CDK, I'm trying to use the auto-generated low-level CloudFormation Resource available at `Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2.cloudformation.InstanceResource_` in the [Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=amazon.cdk.aws.ec2).

My test app is a .NET Core Console App with the [Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=amazon.cdk.aws.ec2) as the only other dependency. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace AWSCDKEval
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a new app. The first argument is used to display a usage message for this app.
            var appArgs = new [] { $"dotnet ${nameof(AWSCDKEval)}" }
                .Concat(args)
                .ToArray();
            var app = new Amazon.CDK.App(appArgs);

            new TestStack(app, "test-aws-cdk-stack-1", new Amazon.CDK.StackProps());

            // Your app must write the return value of app.Run() to standard output. The `cdk init`
            // and `cdk synth` commands require this output.
            Console.WriteLine(app.Run());
        }
    }

    public class TestStack : Amazon.CDK.Stack
    {
        public TestStack(Amazon.CDK.App parent, string name, Amazon.CDK.IStackProps props) : base(parent, name, props)
        {
            new Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2.cloudformation.InstanceResource_(
                this, 
                "testInstance1", 
                new Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2.cloudformation.InstanceResourceProps
                {
                    ImageId = "ami-0f1155cc2cb6b0cfd", // Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Base
                    InstanceType = "t2.micro",
                    KeyName = "my_key",
                    Tags = new []
                    {
                        new Amazon.CDK.Tag { Key = "Name", Value = "test-instance-1" },
                        new Amazon.CDK.Tag { Key = "foo", Value = "bar" }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

You then compile the project and use the CDK to `synth` it into CloudFormation templates and all settings but the `tags` make it.

```
dotnet build <folder-with-code>
cdk synth --output <folder-where-to-write-cf-templates>
```

And the output:

```
Resources:
    testInstance1:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
        Properties:
            ImageId: ami-0f1155cc2cb6b0cfd
            InstanceType: t2.micro
            KeyName: my_key
    CDKMetadata:
        Type: 'AWS::CDK::Metadata'
        Properties:
            Modules: '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2=0.9.1,@aws-cdk/aws-iam=0.9.1,@aws-cdk/cdk=0.9.1,@aws-cdk/cx-api=0.9.1,js-base64=2.4.9'
```

Now, I totally understand that the CDK is in very early stages and not recommended for any dev work, but the best part is the availability of all native resources under the `cloudformation` namespace which I plan to use while the CDK grows.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is [currently a bug in AWS CDK and does work](https://gitter.im/awslabs/aws-cdk?at=5ba2d34b1ee2ca65023fa57e) if you use `typescript` instead of any `C# .NET`. I've logged an [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/746) for the same.